# Backspace, navigation keys and others not working after upgrade to 22.04.03

Tags: keyboard, 22.04, laptop, keys

The following keys are dead after the upgrade:
<kbd>Nav left</kbd>
<kbd>Nav down</kbd>
<kbd>Backspace</kbd>
<kbd>Page down</kbd>
<kbd>G</kbd>
<kbd>H</kbd>

Keyboard is US international with dead keys (definitely is now ;-))

Laptop is D Zbook 14 G1

`lsb_release -a` gives:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
```